# Find and replace a part of the string across all files in a directory

Tags: sed, string

In my codebase i've lines like

```
@driver.find_element(:link, "Create").click
```

and sometimes there can be any string inside '(' and ')'

eg: `@driver.find_element(:name, from_email).click`

I want to replace the lines

```
@driver.find_element(:link, "Create").click
```

and

```
@driver.find_element(:name, from_email).click
```

as

```
click(:link, "Create")
```

and

```
click(:name, from_email)
```

I want the parenthesis and the words inside the parenthesis to be retained after replacing `@driver.find_element` with `click`.

Is there a way to do this across files in different folder levels?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> replace a part of the string across all files in a directory

**find** + ***sed*** solution:

```
find yourfolder -type f -print0 \
    | xargs -0 sed -i.bak -E 's/@driver\.find_element\(([^()]+)\)\.click/click(\1)/'
```

Comment: Thanks Roman. I get this error when i execute "command i expects \ followed by text"..

Comment: @RadheshyamRK, it seems that you on BSD or OSX OS, try my update

Comment: Yes @RomanPerekhrest, i'm on OSX. Sorry forgot to mention that. Your updated command removed the error i was seeing, Now i get this "sed: RE error: illegal byte sequence"

Comment: @RadheshyamRK, see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19242275/re-error-illegal-byte-sequence-on-mac-os-x and this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11287564/getting-sed-error-illegal-byte-sequence-in-bash

Comment: appending LC_CTYPE=C to sed did the trick! thanks for the help!

Comment: I don't know if it matters, but if "any string" includes a string with `(` or `)` in it, the `sed` expression will not work on it.

Comment: @Kusalananda, with *any string* you meant any other text along with searched one?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I'm noting that the OP writes "and sometimes there can be _any string_ inside '(' and ')'", which would presumably include strings containing `(` and `)`.

Comment: @Kusalananda, I can consider that moment if the OP will declaim it as an issue

Answer (score 0):

Using sed with extended regex support (-r or -E):

```
$ sed -E 's/.*(\(.*\))[.](.*)/\2\1/g' <<<$'@driver.find_element(:link, "Create").click'
click(:link, "Create")

$ sed -E 's/.*(\(.*\))[.](.*)/\2\1/g' <<<$'@driver.find_element(:name, from_email).click'
click(:name, from_email)
```

Classic sed , basic regex:

```
$ sed 's/.*\((.*)\)[.]\(.*\)/\2\1/g' <<<$'@driver.find_element(:link, "Create").click'
click(:link, "Create")
```

With awk:

```
$ awk -F'[.(]' '{print $NF "(" $(NF-1)}' <<<$'@driver.find_element(:name, from_email).click'    
click(:name, from_email)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed`:

```
sed 's/@driver.find_element\((:name, from_email)\).click/click\1/;s/@driver.find_element\((:link, "Create")\).click/click\1/'
```

**Examples:**
File before:

```
cat clickReplace 
@driver.find_element(:link, "Create").click
@driver.find_element(:name, from_email).click
@driver.find_element(:name, foobar).click
@driver.find_element(:link, foobar).click
```

File after:

```
sed 's/@driver.find_element\((:name, from_email)\).click/click\1/;s/@driver.find_element\((:link, "Create")\).click/click\1/' clickReplace 
click(:link, "Create")
click(:name, from_email)
@driver.find_element(:name, foobar).click
@driver.find_element(:link, foobar).click
```

Use `sed -i` to change the files "in place".

To do it recursively, use `find` to wherever in your filesystem the files are. E.g.:

```
find /path/to/files/ -type f -exec \
sed -i 's/@driver.find_element\((:name, from_email)\).click/click\1/;s/@driver.find_element\((:link, "Create")\).click/click\1/' {} +
```

Answer (score 0):

Given a *single* file, the following `sed` command will do the substitution on that file:

```
sed 's/@driver.find_element(\(.*\)).click/click(\1)/' file >file.tmp && 
mv file.tmp file
```

We'd like to find all files in a file hierarchy and execute that on all of them:

```
find . -type f \
    -exec sh -c \
    'for n; do
        sed "s/@driver.find_element(\(.*\)).click/click(\1)/" "$n" >"$n.tmp" &&
        mv "$n.tmp" "$n"
    done' sh {} +
```

If you only want to modify files with a particular name, for example `*.js`, just add `-name '*.js'` before the `-exec`.

This assumes that adding `.tmp` to the end of a filename won't accidentally overwrite an existing file.

---

I purposefully did not use `sed -i` since the `-i` is notoriously non-portable between `sed` implementations.